# write text to image

Tags: php, javascript

I have uploaded an image, now I want to write text dynamically anywhere on the uploaded image.
I want that user should himself choose where to write on the image and then save image with text written on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

[Watermark Your Images with Text Using PHP and GD Library](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2008/11/watermark-your-images-with-text-using.html)

[image: Example 1 - After Text Watermark]

The code uses [`imagettftext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) function to write text on an image using true-type fonts.

Comment: This is what i seek that user can write text and move it anywhere on the image.
http://www.online-image-editor.com/

Comment: The post I mentioned was written by me. You are welcome to have a look at the code. It allows you to place the text on arbitrary coordinates. Sorry but I won't tell you exactly what you have to do to match you project's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [image functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php).

Comment: Indeed, combined with AJAX to send where to write and what to write this should be simple enough. :)

Comment: This doesn't solves my purpose.
I want to write dynamically anywhere on the image, user be able to select an area where it can write. For eg: I want to write on the top-rite corner of the image. the size of the textarea will be decided by the user. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may as well try using the powerful ImageMagick library - http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php